# Undefined class constant 'MAIN'

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

We have the following migration:

```
class CreateAccounts extends Migration
{

    public function up()
    {
        $data= [
            "id" => \App\Account::MAIN,
            "container" => null,               
        ];

        \App\Account::create($data);
    }

}
```

And here is the class Account, it contains some constants and methods:

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

    class Account extends MainModel
    {
        const MAIN = 47;
    
    ...
    
    }
```

The migration works fine in our dev server but on production it complaints saying

```
Undefined class constant 'MAIN'
```

The same error from tinker.

Comment: Try run `composer dump-autoload` but it might be that the file name/namespace is incorrect, make sure it is `Account.php` inside the app folder. also if you're using git, check the branch your production server is on.

Comment: Hi, the name is right, and I already tried dump-autoload, but the same keeps happening

Comment: I even changed the line \App\Account::MAIN to Account::MAIN and included an import at the top. Works on dev, but not on production, same error.

Comment: have you directly verified that the file exists in prod (branch issue) the autoload rules are simple but rigid.

Comment: yes, I even opened it. Something "strange" is that in phpstorm I see that other uses of constants in other clases e.g. AnotherClass::ANOTHER_CONSTANT are fine without using \App\AnotherClass (without importing) but it's not the same for the Account class; I have to write \App\Account (even when both clasess are located together).

Comment: I suspect it can be something related to cache? Somehow it's seeing an older version of the file? I tried using php artisan optimize 
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan route:cache
php artisan view:clear
php artisan config:cache composer dump-autoload

Comment: Those other classes use aliases (you can find the list inside `config/app.php` => aliases, or are in the same namespace as where they are called. example if you call Account::Main inside \App\User::class, you dont need to specify the namespace.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. I ended up searching from linux command line to find out if there was a file with the same name somewhere else, and yes, there was an old version of the class (file) that was still at an old location where it was moved from, so php artisan migrate was finding the older version and not seeing the new one. After deleting the file it all worked.

Comment: which could be found using git commands like `git status`

Comment: we use SVN.....

Comment: same, in SVN you can see incoming changes, the file is certainly listed there.

Comment: the file was repeated on the server